# notepad++ regex remove numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a notepad++ text file with:

```
have 9456
do 9823781
no 83270
tell 342
```

and it continues like that.

What is the regex for removing the space and numbers from the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to replace `[0-9 ]+` with empty string with the regex option enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following as your search string:

```
 \d+$
```

Remember to have the *Search Mode* set to *Regular Expression*.

Answer (score 0):

Find space and digits easy as one two three

Search `\s\d+`
Replace all with: `nothing`